# ScheduledExecutorService - safe shutdown and restart if things go bad

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I wanted a little confirmation if this was the right way to go about implementing my use case.

I am working on a swing app. This app when it starts, should launch a service thread at the background, that keeps polling a database and does some stuff at an interval of 30 minutes.

These are the things that need to happen

- Starts off a service that executes at a fixed rate of 30 minutes.
- If an exception happens while the service is executing, it should notify the user and restart itself.
- When the user quits the application, all backround threads should be stopped.

I have written this code below. I needed some confirmation whether this was the right way to go about building something like this. Specifically I had the below questions

- The while(true) loop is used to restart the service when things go bad. Could there be any issues with this? Is there a better way of doing this?
- What is the most reliable way to shutdown the entire thing when the user exits. I want the user's exit to be quick and at the same time the background thread should have completed somewhere in between. Is there someway of making the background thread signify that it has reached a checkpoint and that it can be shutdown? Like for example, if I am looping through many records in the database and when shutdown is called, if the thread is working on one record, it completes working on that record and then proceeds to shutdown?

  ```
  import java.util.concurrent.*;

  public class ScheduledFutureTest {

  private static int counter=0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
          ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
          executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>(){
              @Override
              public Void call() throws Exception {
                  ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                  ScheduledFuture<?> future=schedule(scheduledExecutorService);
                  while(true){
                      try{
                          future.get();
                      }catch (Exception e){
                          System.out.println("Exception caught.. now need to restart scheduler");
                          scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();
                         // restart scheduler
                          scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                          future=schedule(scheduledExecutorService);
                          System.out.println("Restarted the scheduler");
                      }
                  }
              }

              public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService){
                  return scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          System.out.println(counter++);
                          // simulating an exception to occur     
                          if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                              throw new RuntimeException("Exception thrown from runnable - counter ="+counter);
                          }
                      }
                  }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // actually 30 minutes
              }
          });

          // work with other stuff regarding the swing app
          System.out.println(" continuing with working on other stuff ");
      }catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Why not handle the exception inside your `run` method? It would be simpler.

Comment: mmm.. and notify the user via the EDT in case of an exception.. now that's an idea. Thanks.. will consider that.